# 2D graphics with Direct3D

Tags: directx, 2d, direct3d

I'm trying to use Direct3D to render 2D graphics, as recommended by everyone since DirectDraw's deprecation. There really isn't any 3D-ness I care about, and just want to be able to do things like draw lines, circles, and blit images onto each other. My questions are thus

1. I need to load a lot of images from files, and draw them onto each other. Would textures be the way to go?
2. Very stupid question, but I can't seem to find anything: How do you render one surface onto another?
3. Should you render everything onto a single texture and then draw that to screen as a sprite, or just draw many textures?
4. How do you draw lines, etc, onto a texture/surface/sprite? I assume there's a better way than getting a device context and using GDI to draw on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Create 2 triangles forming a quad. Set the UV values appropriately.  UV values are set in the range 0 to 1.  So for a 1024x1024 (Or in fact ANY resolution texture which is why it is done this way) image the top left is 0,0 and the bottom right is 1,1.  [ID3DXSprite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will help you here.
3. Its best to put multiple "frames" in one texture to avoid changing the texture too often (this is expensive).
4. You could use D3DPT_LINELIST/STRIP ... Failing that use 2 triangles (See [ID3DXLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174016%28VS.85%29.aspx)).